# How to build embedding layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to build a text classification model in tensorflow, following one of Francois Chollet's tutorials from his book. I am trying to first create an embedding layer, but it keeps breaking at this stage.

My logic is follows:

- Start with list of strings of text as X and list of integers as y.
- tokenize, vectorize, and pad text data to longest sequence length
- convert each integer label into a one hot encoded array
- feed into an embedding layer with the inputs:

  - input_dim = sum of unique tokens/words (1499 in my case)
  - output_dim = dimension size of embedding vector (starting with 32)
  - input_length = length of max sequence, the same dimension that sequences are padded to (295 in my case)
- pass embedding results into a 32 hidden unit dense layer with relu
- pass those into a 3 hidden unit dense layer with softmax to predict 3 classes

Can someone explain to me what I am getting wrong here? I thought I understood how to instantiate an embedding layer, but is this not the correct understanding?

Here is my code:

```html
# read in raw data
df = pd.read_csv('text_dataset.csv')
samples = df.data.tolist() # list of strings of text
labels = df.sentiment.to_list() # list of integers

# tokenize and vectorize text data to prepare for embedding
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(samples)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(samples)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(f'Found {len(word_index)} unique tokens.')

# setting variables
vocab_size = len(word_index) # 1499
# Input_dim: This is the size of the vocabulary in the text data.
input_dim = vocab_size # 1499
# This is the size of the vector space in which words will be embedded.
output_dim = 32 # recommended by tf
# This is the length of input sequences
max_sequence_length = len(max(sequences, key=len)) # 295
# train/test index splice variable
training_samples = round(len(samples)*.8)

# data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_sequence_length) # shape (499, 295)
# keras automatically pads to maxlen if left without input
data = pad_sequences(sequences)

# preprocess labels into one hot encoded array of 3 classes ([1., 0., 0.])
labels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=3, dtype='float32') # shape (499, 3)

# Create test/train data (80% train, 20% test)
x_train = data[:training_samples]
y_train = labels[:training_samples]
x_test = data[training_samples:]
y_test = labels[training_samples:]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=10,
          batch_size=32,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```html
Found 1499 unique tokens.
Model: "sequential_23"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_21 (Embedding)     (None, 295, 32)           47968     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 295, 32)           1056      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 295, 3)            99        
=================================================================
Total params: 49,123
Trainable params: 49,123
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-f29ef892e38d> in <module>()
     51           epochs=10,
     52           batch_size=32,
---> 53           validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_7 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (399, 3)
```

To troubleshoot, I have been commenting out layers to try to see whats going on. I found that the problem persists all the way up to the first layer, making me think I have a poor understanding of the Embedding layer. See below:

```html
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim, output_dim, input_length=max_sequence_length))
# model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Which results in:

```html
Found 1499 unique tokens.
Model: "sequential_24"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_22 (Embedding)     (None, 295, 32)           47968     
=================================================================
Total params: 47,968
Trainable params: 47,968
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-63d1b96db467> in <module>()
     51           epochs=10,
     52           batch_size=32,
---> 53           validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    129                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    130                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 131                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    132                 if not check_batch_axis:
    133                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected embedding_22 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (399, 3)
```

Comment: I am not a Keras expert. Yet, typically a Dense layer would expect an batch of flat input i.e. shape would have only 2 inputs like [None, 295]. Since you are trying to feed a tokenized sentence at once that has 3 dimensions [BS, length, embedding_size] you should probably use a sort of convolution layer. Other option would be to flatten examples in your batch from [295, 32] to [295*32] - this is not what you want but would allow you to run a quick test if my suggestion is reasonable.

Comment: @y.selivonchyk Thanks for your input. I added a Flatten layer and that worked, my model compiled and fit. This is probably too big a question for this venue, but why do you say adding a flatten layer is not what I want?

Comment: It might still work depending on your usecase. Lets say you use a  conv layer that spans over 2-20 words, it would have 20*32+1 parameters while fully connected neuron would have 295*32+1. with conv layer the neuron would look at a single location at a time, while a FC neuron would always see the whole sentence and would depend on the position of the word in the sentence a lot more heavily. It is just a gist of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dense layer in keras is expected to take a flat input with only 2 dimensions `[BATCH_SIZE, N]`. Output of an embedding layer for a sentence has 3 diemnsions: `[BS, SEN_LENGTH, EMBEDDING_SIZE]`.

There are 2 options to tackle that:

1. Flatten the output of embedding layer: `model.add(Flatten())` before the first dense layer;
2. Use a convolutional layer (would recommend that): `model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))`